# AspectJ Maven Plugin wont compile my project after upgrading to java 11

Tags: java, maven, aop, aspectj, aspectj-maven-plugin

I am trying to upgrade a project from java 8 to 11. I have updated the pom but i get an error about aspectJ not being able to compile it when running the build.

Here is the error i get below.

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:aspectj-maven-plugin:1.8:compile (default) on project name: Execution default of goal org.codehaus.mojo:aspectj-maven-plugin:1.8:compile failed: Plugin org.codehaus.mojo:aspectj-maven-plugin:1.8 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Could not find artifact com.sun:tools:jar:11.0.18 at specified path C:\Program Files (x86)\Amazon Corretto\jdk11.0.18_10/../lib/tools.jar -> [Help 1]
```

Here is my parent pom file - is there something wrong with it?

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.amor</groupId>
    <artifactId>name-parent</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <version>1.1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>NAME Parent</name>
    <modules>
        <module>..\name-plus</module>
        <module>..\name-application</module>        
    </modules>
    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.8.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>11</source>
                        <target>11</target>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <inherited>true</inherited>
                    <configuration>
                        <testFailureIgnore>false</testFailureIgnore>
                        <forkMode>once</forkMode>
                        <excludes>
                            <exclude>**/*DbUnitTest.java</exclude>
                        </excludes>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.11</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>11</source>
                        <target>11</target>
                        <complianceLevel>11</complianceLevel>
                        <aspectLibraries>
                            <aspectLibrary>
                                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                                <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
                            </aspectLibrary>
                        </aspectLibraries>
                        <aspectDirectory>src/main/java</aspectDirectory>
                        <showWeaveInfo>true</showWeaveInfo>
                    </configuration>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>compile</goal>
                                <goal>test-compile</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>sql-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.4</version>
                    <dependencies>
                        <!-- The oracle JDBC driver -->
                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>com.oracle.jdbc</groupId>
                            <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
                            <version>12.2.0.1</version>
                        </dependency>
                    </dependencies>
                    <configuration>
                        <driver>oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver</driver>
                        <url>jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:NGC</url>
                        <username>ngc_user</username>
                        <password>ngc</password>
                        <onError>continue</onError>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.4</version>
                    <dependencies>
                        <!-- The oracle JDBC driver -->
                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>com.oracle.jdbc</groupId>
                            <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
                            <version>12.2.0.1</version>
                        </dependency>
                    </dependencies>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>test-jar</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
    <reporting>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1.1</version> 
                <configuration>
                    <dependencyLocationsEnabled>false</dependencyLocationsEnabled>
                    <dependencyDetailsEnabled>false</dependencyDetailsEnabled>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </reporting>
    
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-framework-bom</artifactId>
                <version>4.0.0.RELEASE</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-security-bom</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.10.RELEASE</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>        
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!--
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-mock</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.8</version>
        </dependency>
        -->
        
        <!-- could only update this to 1.8 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
            <artifactId>quartz</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.velocity</groupId>
            <artifactId>velocity</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- cant update this -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.10.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- upgraded to 5.6.15 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-ehcache</artifactId>
            <version>5.6.15.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- upgraded to 6.0.0 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- upgraded to 5.0.0 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>     
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>   
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-cglib-repack</artifactId>
            <version>2.1_3</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- removed - no longer needed to add explicitly after spring 3.2
        <dependency>
            <groupId>cglib</groupId>
            <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.0</version>
        </dependency>    
        -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
            <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
            <version>2.12.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- cant update this -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.directwebremoting</groupId>
            <artifactId>dwr</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- cant update this -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>3.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.velocity</groupId>
            <artifactId>velocity-tools</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sourceforge.jexcelapi</groupId>
            <artifactId>jxl</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.12</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
            <version>1.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- cant update this -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.easymock</groupId>
            <artifactId>easymock</artifactId>
            <version>3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ognl</groupId>
            <artifactId>ognl</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>c3p0</groupId>
            <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.15</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <!-- cant update this -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0-alpha-1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- cant update this -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- cant update this -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle.database.jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
            <version>12.2.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- cant update this -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.19</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- only able to update to 4.0.0 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>hsqldb</groupId>
            <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.0.10</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>3.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- cant update this -->
        <dependency>
              <groupId>org.dbunit</groupId>
              <artifactId>dbunit</artifactId>
              <version>2.7.3</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
          <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
          <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
          <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
          <artifactId>jaxb-core</artifactId>
          <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
          <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
          <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

**ignore**

adding more text at the bottom since it wont let me post as it looks like there is too much code lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated my `pom.xml` and changed it to use `com.nickwongdev` instead. However, according to the comments, `dev.aspectj` should be used instead.

It doesn't look like the version I was using works for Java 11 [here](https://www.eclipse.org/lists/aspectj-users/msg15379.html).

```
<groupId>dev.aspectj</groupId> 
<artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId> 
<version>1.13.1</version>
```

Comment: That fork is outdated and and was retired years ago. You should use [`dev.aspectj:aspectj-maven-plugin:1.13.1`](https://github.com/dev-aspectj/aspectj-maven-plugin) instead. If you upgrade its `aspectjtools` plugin dependency accordingly, you can use it with any new AspectJ and JDK version, e.g. the current AspectJ 1.9.19 and AspectJ 19 or the soon-to-be-released 1.9.20 and Java 20.